# mvc3 IModelBinder and url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, imodelbinder

I'm having a problem using iModelBinder with url in the format of

http://localhost/controller/action/id/value

the action would be the function in the controller
the id/value is ie. id=12

When I try the above link i receive a 404 error page not found, and looking at the stack I can understand that MVC is looking for a path it does not understand.

using the following works

http://localhost/controller/action?id=value

If anyone as any idea if this problem can be resolved, I would really like to be able to use "/" as separators.

Vince

Comment: Any particular reason not to leave off id and let your route definition bind Id for you like most MVC apps would?

Comment: Hi, a lot of the processing is done client side, the MVC site is going back to a SOLR engine for the data. So far the only way I could figure out how to pass the client selections back to the server was to pass them bakc using the URL. The problem with that it kinda breaks the MVC standard, yet i could not really figure another way of accomplishing it any other way

Comment: @Adam: There is a reason—yes. Because say you have #!/x/5,2/y/7 or #!/x/5,2 or #!/y/7, but NEVER #!/y/7 or #!/y/7/x/5,2... the params must always be in the same order, lest we have 2 URLs that point to the exact same content.

Comment: @Vince - You should post your view and controller action(s) to give a better indication of what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @sfjedi - I'm not sure I understand your reasoning?  What is #! meant to represent?  You can have #!/y/7 but never #!/y/7?  So which can you have (although i'm not sure what either is).

Comment: @sfjedi you say theres a reason, but is that actually the reason in the OPS case. If so, then define a base id and use named parameters like the rest of web apps or simply use named parameters for everything. Im well aware of what happens if you have a route with /x/y but using parameter names in a url asking for trouble.

Comment: @Vince - why can they only go as part of the path with SOLR? Thats the only thing supported is that syntax? any documentation you can link to for that?

Comment: @Dangerous - I made a mistake saying NEVER #!/y/7, but definitely not #!/y/7/x/5 is my point. x and y could represent shirt size and shirt color, respectively. It doesn't matter. What matters is that the parameters always come in the same order and never backwards or mixed.

Comment: @Dangerous — #! is meant to represent a URL that has changed via JavaScript, so http://yourdomain.com/#!/x/5/y/7 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should really be in the format:

```
http://localhost/controller/action/id
```

For example:

```
http://localhost/products/index/1
```

And the id should then be specified in the controller action.  For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
    ...
```

The route specified in the global.asax file will specify the format of the url.  For the above url the default route will suffice:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then the default model binder will automatically bind your id (i.e. 1 in the above url) to the int id in the action.

Like Adam was suggesting, I don't think you should specify the name of the id in the url as it is automatically bound to for you by the default model binder.

Comment: the controller receives an IEnumerable object, that the IModelBinder compiles from the query first. "public ActionResult GetSomething(IEnumerable<list> myObject) {}

Comment: @Vince - I'm not sure I follow. How does this relate to your question about the .../id/value part of the url?